# How to use overlay effect in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs

How to use Image overlay in ReactJS? I am making a movie site. 
Here is the link : [Project](https://angry-babbage-e76079.netlify.com/)
I want to use overlay effect when the user hovers over the image.
When the user hovers over the image I want to show tagline with the overlay effect on the image.
Here is the link I tried : [reference](http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/index.html)
But, it's not working in React.
Here is the code :
In image tag i want to add overlay effect.

```
    <div className="main-description"   >                                                                                                 
    <img src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+res.poster_path} 
    className="result- image"/>

    <b className="result-titles"  >{res.original_title}</b>


    <div className="extra-description">

    <div className="rating_time_score_container">

    <div className="sub-title Rating-data"><b>

    Imdb

    <span className="details" > {res.vote_average}/10 </span></b></div>

    <div className="time-data">

    <b><span className="time">

    <i className="fa fa-clock-o"></i> </span> <span className="details">                                                
    {res.time_str}</span>

    </b>

   </div>


   </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: You should provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do with CSS, It would of been nice to have a link to your github but i\I tracked down your code (since its open source) and I took and look. I suggest using a package like this one: https://github.com/ethanselzer/react-hover-observer
or even bootstraps classic react package like this one:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/

Then what you can do is update the state of your application and add the overlay that way. Hope that helped and good luck with your project